# Jquery: get value of specific hidden field

Tags: jquery

Im generating a dynamic list in jqueury, and when clicked i need to get the specific value of the hidden fields in THAT list element, but i am struggling.

```
<li class="trigger">
    <a class="" href="#">Aktiv</a>
    <input name="hrDesc"   value='Value 1'>
    <input name="hrCount" value="Value 2">
</li>

<li class="trigger`">
     <a class="" href="#">Uaktiv</a>
     <input name="hrDesc"  value="Value 3">
     <input name="hrCount" value="Value 4">
</li>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$('.trigger').live( "click", function(){  
    alert (  $("[name='hrDesc']").serialize() );
});​
```

The problem is that is always returns all values of "hrDesc"
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware that [`.live()` is deprecated](http://liveisdeprecated.com)? You should use `.on()` (jQuery 1.7+) or `.delegate()` instead.

Comment: @nbrooks - I can't see anything wrong with the `input` elements. They will default to the `text` type.

Comment: @james yep sorry I didn't know that the `/>` closing was unnecessary in html (as opposed to xhtml) -- just looked that up to be sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.trigger').live( "click", function(){
  alert ( 
          $(this)             // point to current clicked li
              .find("[name='hrDesc']")  // find specific input within clicked li
              .serialize() 
        );
});​
```

#### Note

Instead of `.live()` try to use **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)** for delegate event handling with jQuery 1.7+